# keeping apps and data through LineageOS upgrade

Tags: updates, lineageos, data

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 3 and I am in process of upgrading LineageOS from 16 to 18. [The instructions](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/hlte/upgrade) indicate to wipe the data partition in step 8.  Will this remove my installed apps and data?  I know how to do a backup and restore using adb but I wondered if there is a way to upgrade lineageOS and keep the apps and data without backing up and restoring.

Comment: The link you have posted does not work. Yes wiping the user data partition delete all app data and apps. It is difficult to guess if this is really necessary. May be the step to clear data is mainly there to avoid potential problems. I already had the case that switching from stock ROM to a totally different custom ROM had worked without wiping data.

Comment: backup apps with [Migrate](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/3862763), messages with [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) and *'adb pull -a /sdcard'* all your files to PC

Comment: I fixed the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [changelog for LineageOS 18](https://lineageos.org/Changelog-25/),

> Please note that if you’re currently on an official build, you DO NOT need to wipe your device, unless your device’s wiki page *specifically* dictates otherwise, as is needed for some devices with massive changes, such as a repartition. (emphasis mine)

While the [Instructions for upgrading the Note 3 (hlte)](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/hlte/upgrade) as mentioned in the original question specifically says

> 8. Wipe your data partition (this is usually named “Wipe”, or “Format”)

So I think the answer is definitively **No**

As additional evidence, I tried an upgrade to 18.1 on a second backup phone I have without doing the data partition wipe and it will not boot properly.

So for those upgrading a Note 3 (hlte), please do a backup of everything you want to have after the upgrade. I use ADB to do this but many people use a custom recovery to do a nandroid backup